# Resize image to fit window in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am using Qt to construct an application. My MainWindow consists of an image of a map which I would like to be resized to the fit the window. This means when the window gets smaller the image gets smaller and vice versa. When the user selects a point on that image I want to remove this feature. I am new to Qt and haven't been able to figure this out. I am using QGraphicsView for this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "When the user selects a point on that image I want to remove this feature."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGraphicsView::fitInView